# Httpclient download page

Tags: android, download, httpclient, html

i need download page but i don t how... :)

```
private static DefaultHttpClient client;
private HttpGet request;
private HttpResponse response;
....  // some code
client  = getNewHttpClient();
....
response = client.execute(mypage.cz);   
....
 try {

 in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String line = "";
    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
         sb.append(line + NL);
    }

    page = sb.toString();
    in.close();
    }
```

After i save code like html file and opent it.. But it looks like this
     [image: 1 pic]

But i need it to look like this. It can be dowloaded without pictures

[image: 2 pic]

Any idea how to download page by htppclient? :)

Comment: You also need to download all css styles. As any browser do.

Comment: I don't know how to program it but what you need to do is,  download all the resources thatthe webpage is pointing to.. Try downloading a webpage from pc, you will notice that the folder that you downloaded tbe webpage in, will contain many files that the .html file you downloaded requires to show up properly with various css and png's

Comment: Thanks guys.... I dowloaded whole page in computer a copy ....css to phone and change path in code to ..css and it works! :))